AG Grid Update: startEditingCell removed charPress property
I've recently upgraded from ag-grid 27 to 32. In the latest version, charPress is no longer a valid property for the config object on startEditingCell. Here is my use case:
Below the ag-grid implementation, I display a list of elements that can be clicked on. Whenever the user clicks on an element, I put the selected cell into an editable state and I copy the value of what the user clicked on into the input box. I could previously do this with something like:
useEffect(() => {
 const selectedListItemsString = selectedListItems.join(' ')
 gridRef.current!.api.startEditingCell({
          rowIndex: rowIndex,
          colKey: myColumn,
          charPress: selectedListItemsString,
        });
}, [selectedListItems])

Now that charPress has been removed, I can't find a way to automatically set the editable value. Are there any other solutions that may work here?
I've checked the documentation and I don't see any other work around.
